# TabBarController changes color when presented or pushed again

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a storyboard like this: NavigationController -> A -> B -> TabBarController -> C

When it's following the natural cycle, the UITabBarController shows normal tabBar, like this:

[image]

But when I'm on "C" and unwind to "B" and present/push TabBarController again, it appears like this:

[image]

I tried so many things already and nothing works.

**EDIT**

This purplish color is the current color of my navigation bar, but I haven't set this color. The tab bar is set to translucent only on storyboard.

Here's the code showing how I'm instantiating the UITabBarController:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as! UITabBarController

if let navbar = self.navigationController {
     navbar.pushViewController(destinatin, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Well there is some dispute but generally you shouldn't put a TabBarController in a navigation stack like that. It's intended to be a top level controller. Are you setting the color of the tabBar anywhere?

Comment: What @random said is correct. I'd be willing to be that your TabBarVC is being loaded with another view on top of it. Where do you think that purplish color is coming from?

Comment: On what @dylanthelion said, alternatively could you be adding a view below it? Is the tabBar translucent? Posting some code will help also.

Comment: I've edited my question so you can have more information! Thanks!